# Change asp:ImageButton ImageUrl to default URL after accepting file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback, imagebutton

When the user clicks in an ImageButton, I want the Image to change to a "Loading" gif, and then change back when the button finishes its function on the server side.

Now, in every place, I can do this without worrying about changing the image back, because I'm using javascript to change the image to the loading gif, thus the postback automatically reverts the change to default.

BUT I have this ImageButton that makes a download of a file to the client side, and it doesn't postback after the function finishes because the user still have to choose between Open / Save file.

**ASP**

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgPonto" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ver e-mail">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="linkEmailFile" OnClientClick="this.src='../Image/progress.gif';" OnCommand="lnkEmailFile_Click" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ID") %>' ImageUrl="~/Image/openEmail.png" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
protected void lnkEmailFile_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Notification notif = NotificationBLL.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
    EmailMng.Management.Smtp.MailOpenEml(notif.SerializedEmailFile, notif.ID.ToString());

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/outlook";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + notif.ID + ".eml");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"~/Files/") + notif.ID + ".eml");
    //(sender As ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/Image/openEmail.png" <- This does not work...
}
```

I need to find a way to change the image back to the default image when the client receives the file, but I can't find how

Comment: I'm not sure about your JavaScript code but you can check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
A promise method may be your answer

Comment: sorry for the delay, I was placed in another project for a while. How can the promisse method see if the response has transmitted a file?